# audio progress bar in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to create a web audio player using angularjs. 
I'm not using the html5 "controls" attribute for the player since I want a specific style. I have play/pause/next/prev buttons but I've been struggling trying to create an interactive progress bar. I've read different options to create "static" progress bars (for example using bootstrap) that shows the progress but the user can't seek and jump to a different part of the song. I think I'm missing something, it can't be that difficult to create a seekable progress bar. Does anybody has an idea about how this should be done? 
thanks

Edit: other possibility could be using some of those libraries that wrap the audio element and add functionalities. Did anybody use some of this libraries?

Comment: you may go directly for http://www.wavesurfer.fm/

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know about angularjs but I made something like that with some simple js code,
so you'll need to get the left(x) position of the progressbar and the left position(x) that mouse is clicked on progressbar and the difference of diference of them (clickX - progressbarX) you will have to devide by the width of the progressbar so you'll get the time you need to jump on player in a float number multiply by audio length and you will get the exact time to jump to;

So it is (clickX - progressbarX)/progressbarWidth*audioLength

Here is the function I used

`

```
function setCurrentTime(event){

    var posX = event.clientX;
    var aud = document.getElementById('player');
    rect = aud.getBoundingClientRect();
    aud.currentTime = parseInt((((posX-rect.x)/600)*v.duration));

}
```

`

And the html code

`<progress onclick="setCurrentTime(event)" value="0" max="1"></progress>`

Comment: thanks, that's a good approach, but I think it must be something easier, I mean, if you use "controls" property from HTML5 you have everything with 0 lines of js, I'm trying to find out if it's possible to use only the progress bar from those controls or something similar